# Aptana Studio 3 plugin doesnt get installed properly on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, aptana, aptana3, eclipse-juno

I have Eclipse Juno running on 64bit windows 7, I tried installing Aptana Studio 3 plugin for eclipse. The installation goes fine, and aptana plugin shows up in the Installed plugin list too as follows:
[image]

But thats it! I cant see Aptana anywhere else in eclipse, not in preferences,perspectives, views nowhere!
A strange thing i noticed was that while installing aptana plugin, i ***wasn't*** shown any security warning dialogue box telling me that its an unsigned plugin, something that i was expecting.

Has anyone else faced this problem before? Am i going wrong anywhere? please help.

**EDIT**: The same problem persists with Eclipse Indigo too.

Comment: Juno is still quite new. I had to go back to Indigo due to some incompatible plugins (i.e. Android ADT).

Comment: ADT works fine on Juno, also, I have the same problem with Eclipse Indigo, forgot to add that to the question, did it now.

Comment: Sure, ADT works fine on Juno...until you try to copy and paste with the keyboard. Then it doesn't work. Maybe they'll fix it in r21...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself! after looking at the error logs i realized that i had previously added a archive file to install aptana from disk (failed attempt).It was mentioned in the logs at several places, dont know why, but when i removed that repository Aptana installed fine on eclipse. :)